# Algorithm for searching a value in two arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

**Task:** A and B are arrays of natural numbers. A is an incrementally sorted array and B is randomly ordered one. K is some arbitrary natural number. Find an effective algorithm which determines all possible pairs of indexes (i,j) such that A[i]+B[j]=K.

Is this algorithm the most efficient?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int A[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 124};
            int B[] = {4, 1, 10, 5};
            int k = 10;
            int i = 0, n = A.length, m = B.length;
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (i < n){
                if (A[i] >= k) {
                    break;
                }else {
                    int j = 0;
                    while(j < m) {
                        if (A[i] + B[j] == k) {
                            result.add("i = " + i + " j = " + j);
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            for(int z = 0; z < result.size(); z++) {
                System.out.println(result.get(z));
            }
}
```

Comment: Numbers in array `A` are distinct?

Comment: Iterate numbers in B and for each b in B, binary-search for k-b in A.

Comment: "Is this algorithm the most efficient" No. You could start from the middle of your A table. Then go down or up depending of the result of A[i] + B[j]. That would be more efficient, so it can't be the most efficient. **EDIT**: Actually that's what @tobias_k is proposing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the algorithm is not very efficient. While you `break` as soon as you find an `a` in `A` which is greater than `k`, you still have to test all combinations of `a` and `b` before that, giving your algorithm a complexity of O(m n), with n being the number of elements if `A` and m the number of elements in `B`.

Instead, I'd suggest the following:

- loop over all the elements `b` in `B`
- determine `a = K - b`
- use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the index of `a` in `A`, if it exists
- if `a` exists in `A`, print the indices of `a` and `b`

This makes use of the fact that since `A` is sorted, we can quickly determine whether for a given `b`, an `a` such that `a + b = k` exists in `A`. The reverse is not possible, as `B` is randomly ordered. The total complexity for this is O(m log n).

Comment: Some more optimizations: First, binary-search for `k` in `A` and then use that index as the upper-bound for all the other binary-searches, and if `b > k`, don't search at all.

Comment: This answer is correct only if there are no duplicates in `A`.

Comment: @DAle That's a very good point. You can still use the binary search, but from the index found, you'd also have to check and print the previous and next indices until you find a different `a`.

Comment: In the worst case, `A` and `B` contains single values `a` and `b` such that `a+b=K`. Printing all the matching pairs of indexes will take at least `(n*m)` operation. So no algorithm can go under `O(n*m)`.

Comment: @fjardon Yes, in the extreme case that there are in fact n * m solutions, the algorithm will take n * m time, but in the general case, where there are none or few duplicates, the complexity should still be O(mlogn).